# SAS-merge one to many

Tags: merge, sas

I attempt use following code to combine two datasets. It's a one to many combination situation. I want to achieve the final result as shown in the pic. However, it continuelly failed. Does one one could help me
[image]

```
proc sql; 
create table temp2.ddfull as 
select a.*, b.*
from temp2.ddoption as a left join temp2.ddunderprice as b
on a.tt=b.tt;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins involving datetime values can be problematic.  Despite what you see, the TT values might not be equal in the two sets, since datetime values can have subsecond resolution (and with a DATETIME format they might be rendered with some degree of rounding).

This could cause two different values to appear the same with the format applied, when they actually aren't.  This would also prevent inner join conditions, and cause Open_Bid to come over as missing in a left join.

Can you see if the following works?

```
proc sql; 
  create table temp2.ddfull as 
    select a.*, b.*
    from temp2.ddoption as a left join temp2.ddunderprice as b
    on put(a.tt, datetime16.)=put(b.tt, datetime16.);
quit;
```

This will impact performance since two PUT functions will have to be called on each comparison.  If you have another key in the sets that can be used as a join variable, I'd use that instead.